# can't access certain file types in media file in django local server

Tags: django

when i try to acess a file with pdf or mp4 that exsit in the media folder
using dirict link to the file

```
`http://127.0.0.1:7500/media/1.pdf`
```

> the broswer just load forever with no errors

but if i try to acess a jpg file in the same folder it works fine

```
http://127.0.0.1:7500/media/1.jpg
```

> this will work and show the image

i trid some sloutions like add this to the settings but same problem
`ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES = ['*']` .
this is my confgration of the media folder in the **settings**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')]
```

and i this is from the **urls**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i also trid several browsers all gave me the same problem.
i tried to run it on another pc that is using linux it works fine on the other pc but not on mine

```
i'm using Windows 
DJANGO VERSION 4.2.2
```

i have created a new project it has the same problem so the problem is not from the project but i can't slove it